# How can other people open a built app made with flutter desktop?

Tags: macos, flutter, flutter-desktop

I want to know if is possible to send a built app to my coworkers without them having to execute commands like `flutter run -d macOS` or even installing Flutter.

I tried sending them the `build` folder and executing the app inside `macos/Build/Products/Release` but it says `

---

`

It is as easy as right clicking it and open it for it to work, but I also want to know if there is a way to `sign it` or something so it can be opened easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not send people the entire build folder, just the `.app`.

A Flutter application built for macOS is just a macOS application, build by a relatively standard Xcode project. You can sign it the way you would any other macOS application, either by setting up the Xcode project with your signing information, or manually signing it after it's built with the standard tools. Either way, there's nothing Flutter-specific about the process.